# Powershell Export csv from for loop

Tags: powershell

The following code gets a file from FTP server, stores it in a FTP location, then loops through each record and removes duplicates. Finally, exports csv. All this is working fine except it is taking long for the final csv to get exported. Is there a better way to code in order to make the process faster?

```
 
Get-SFTPFile -SFTPSession $Session -RemoteFile "/stms/inbound/Working_Titles_Primary.csv" -LocalPath "$env:TEMP"  

if ($? -eq $false) {return}


 $WT = import-csv "$env:TEMP\Working_Titles_Primary.csv"  
 
 if ((Test-Path -Path "C:\Scripts_Dev\MasterScript\WorkingTitles.csv") -eq $True) {Remove-Item "C:\Scripts_Dev\MasterScript\WorkingTitles.csv" -Force}
 remove-Item "$env:TEMP\Working_Titles_Primary.csv" -Force #Removes file from Temp folder
 $noDupes = @()
 

 $Output =   foreach ($aa in $WT)
   {

        if($aa.PF_USER_ID -in $noDupes)
        {
         
        }

        else{
        
          New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{

                OLO_CODE  = $aa.OLO_CODE 
                PF_USER_ID = $aa.PF_USER_ID
                ACTIVE_INDICATOR = $aa.ACTIVE_INDICATOR
                LAST_DAY_EMPLOYED = $aa.LAST_DAY_EMPLOYED
                APPT_DATE = $aa.APPT_DATE
                EMPLOYEE_TYPE = $aa.EMPLOYEE_TYPE
                FIRST_NAME = $aa.FIRST_NAME
                LAST_NAME = $aa.LAST_NAME
  } | Select-Object OLO_CODE,PF_USER_ID,ACTIVE_INDICATOR,EMPLOYEE_TYPE,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME | Export-csv -Path "C:\Scripts_Dev\MasterScript\WorkingTitles.csv" -Append 
        }
      $noDupes += ($aa.PF_USER_ID)
       
    }
```

Comment: [1] stop using `+=` on arrays. they are fixed size, so that forces making a new, one-bigger array. instead, assign the output of the loop to a $Var. ///// [2] use `[PSCustomObject]` instead of `New-Object` to build your objects. the 1st is faster than the 2nd - AND it keeps the order of props. ///// [3] that means you can skip the `Select-Object` that you are using to get things in the proper order. ///// [4] use `-notin` instead of `-in` in this >>> `if($aa.PF_USER_ID -in $noDupes)` <<< to avoid the empty `if` result and then an `else` block.

Comment: also, test your steps with `Measure-Command` to see where the slow parts are that need working on. [*grin*]

Comment: Personally I'd use `Group` like `$WT|Group PF_USER_ID|%{$_.Group[0]}|Select OLO_CODE,PF_USER_ID,ACTIVE_INDICATOR,EMPLOYEE_TYPE,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME|Export-Csv "C:\Scripts_Dev\MasterScript\WorkingTitles.csv" -NoType` That will group records by PF_USER_ID and then get the first entry for each group. It also avoids rebuilding arrays, as mentioned by Lee Dailey, and stops you from having to append things to a CSV one line at a time.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks for taking your time to comment on this. I had the same idea before but unfortunately, I couldn't accomplish it using Group based on my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Lee_Dailey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) comment, here is how you can make your code run faster.

```
Get-SFTPFile -SFTPSession $Session -RemoteFile "/stms/inbound/Working_Titles_Primary.csv" -LocalPath "$env:TEMP"  

if (-not $?) {break}

$WT = import-csv "$env:TEMP\Working_Titles_Primary.csv"  
 
if (Test-Path -Path "C:\Scripts_Dev\MasterScript\WorkingTitles.csv")
{
    Remove-Item "C:\Scripts_Dev\MasterScript\WorkingTitles.csv" -Force
}

Remove-Item "$env:TEMP\Working_Titles_Primary.csv" -Force #Removes file from Temp folder

$index = [system.collections.generic.list[string]]::new()
$output = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()

foreach ($i in $WT)
{
    $z = $i.PF_USER_ID.ToLower()

    if($index.contains($z))
    {
        continue
    }

    $index.Add($z)

    $output.Add(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            OLO_CODE  = $i.OLO_CODE 
            PF_USER_ID = $i.PF_USER_ID
            ACTIVE_INDICATOR = $i.ACTIVE_INDICATOR
            LAST_DAY_EMPLOYED = $i.LAST_DAY_EMPLOYED
            APPT_DATE = $i.APPT_DATE
            EMPLOYEE_TYPE = $i.EMPLOYEE_TYPE
            FIRST_NAME = $i.FIRST_NAME
            LAST_NAME = $i.LAST_NAME
    }) 
}

if($output)
{
    $output|Export-csv -Path "C:\Scripts_Dev\MasterScript\WorkingTitles.csv"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Santiago. I tested this and this worked like a charm.

Comment: @Nishanth Disk I/O was the main problem on your code, whenever possible you really want to avoid appending to a file on each iteration of a loop.

Comment: Thank you @lee Haidley. Your feedback helped.

Comment: Did you mean to say the major problem here was that I was using arrays instead of list and arrays are not efficient when it comes to handling large no. of records? I'm new to powershell. Just trying to understand what didn't work before and what worked now. One thing I clearly see here is you used "continue" for skipping the records that are already in the list (this is efficient compared to what I've written).

Comment: @Nishanth yeah, so Disk I/O was one of the problems the second problem was you were using a `[System.Array]` which is the standard PS array and is really slow compared to `ArrayList` or `GenericList` there are lots of articles on this regard, for ex https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-speed/. It's pretty interesting read if you're interested on the subject